# Title of SliverAppBar.large not visible

Tags: flutter

I have an app that uses a sliver app bar.large for the app bar and I want to set a background image for the SliverAppBar. I tried setting it with the the flexibleSpace parameter but the title is not visible because of it. How can I solve this?